# Error while using ADAL.net AcquireTokenAsync call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am exploring Azure Active Directory. I am trying to see whether I can use my own login page with custom user id/password controls to capture the user credentials and validate against Azure AD. I am using ADAL.net to implement this, however I get an error "parsing_wstrust_response_failed: Parsing WS-Trust response failed". I get this error on the last line of the below code.

The below is my code:

```
string AppIdURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppIdUrl"];
            UserCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential("testuser@domain.com", "test123");
            AuthenticationContext aContext = new AuthenticationContext(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AADInstance"]);
            AuthenticationResult result = aContext.AcquireTokenAsync(AppIdURL, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"], uc).Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please first click [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) to view the constraints and limitations of the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow . Base on your error message , is the user federated with WS-Trust ? Please provide more information about your current configuration to help us reproduce this error .

In fact, Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow is not recommend. This should only be used when there is a high degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged application), and when other authorization grant types are not available (such as an authorization code).

If your aim is to customize the sign-in page ,such as add company branding to your sign-in page , you could click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-branding-custom-signon-azure-portal) for how to customize the sign-in page .